# Safari style 'share' popover view in app

Tags: objective-c

I was wondering if there was any built in control to allow you to popup a view similar to the share option in Safari.

Instead of a standard action sheet it seems to use customised buttons.

Is this functionality available to use with a standard UIWebview?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s new in iOS 6, and it’s called a UIActivityViewController. See its [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the associated [HI guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW121).

Comment: Fantastic. Just what i needed